# How to bind to a property in view but not in viewmodel?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a few controls, the values of which are used **in the view** but aren't of any concern **in the view model**. I'd like to bind the controls to properties in the view without having to replicate them down to view model.

According to [a similar question's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11635465/1525840), it's possible and I'm using the following code to achieve that. However, when I don't see the expected results, so I'm guessing that I'm unintentionally binding to a flagpole, not the intended property.

XAML

```
<DatePicker x:Name="Uno"
            SelectedDate="{Binding StartDate, Source={x:Static Application.Current}}"
            SelectedDateChanged="DatePicker_OnSelectedDateChanged" />
<DatePicker x:Name="Due"
            SelectedDate="{Binding StartDate, Source={x:Static Application.Current}}"
            SelectedDateChanged="DatePicker_OnSelectedDateChanged" />
```

C#

```
public partial class ViewWindow : Window
{
  public static DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

What am I missing in my code? Or have I misunderstood the reply and going about it all the wrong way?

Comment: are you following MVVM pattern?

Comment: @un-lucky Sorry for being sarcastic in my previous comment. Let's try again. I feel that your question is pointless here as the title clearly states that I want to bind to something else than the view model. Whether I'm using it or not is hence outside of the question's scope. Kindly, please view the reply below on how to achieve the requested binding. (Unless you've got a deeper thought behind your comment, in which case, I'm all ears.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
x:Static Application.Current
```

tries to set [`Application.Current`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.current%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as a binding source for the particular binding expression. But, obviously, you don't want to access something like `Application.Current.StartDate` (I suppose, that your `App` class doesn't have such property defined).

Actually, I've missed `static` keyword from your property definition.
If you're on the .NET 4.5 or higher, you can write binding path this way for static properties:

```
<DatePicker x:Name="Uno"
            SelectedDate="{Binding Path=(local:ViewWindow.StartDate)}"
            SelectedDateChanged="DatePicker_OnSelectedDateChanged" />
```

`local` here is a namespace, where `ViewWindow` is defined.
Otherwise, use [`RelativeSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) markup extension (this also fits the case, when the property is instance):

```
<DatePicker x:Name="Uno"
            SelectedDate="{Binding StartDate, 
              RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
            SelectedDateChanged="DatePicker_OnSelectedDateChanged" />
```

Comment: Hazaa! That's a green check for ya. If you also care to shed some light on what I've been doing (maybe it's not wrong but not applicable for my need's case) with *Source* and *Application.Current* etc., there's also a cool +1 waiting at the top on my rat's left button.

Comment: @KonradViltersten you were using an `Application` (not a `Window`) for the source of your binding. If the property you were binding to was in the `Window` and not in the `Application` (as defined per `Application.Current`), how did you expect it to find it?

Comment: @KonradViltersten Notice in the answer you linked, they do define the property in the `Application`, you have it in the window/view

Comment: @Jcl The explanation makes sense, now that it's stated. I was assuming that my window **was** the application (it's definitely **an** application, right?) as it's the "start as" in my program. But it was **assuming** and not **reasoning**, so I'm glad that we've got that clearly sorted out. There might be others who make that assumption too.

Comment: A Window is far from being an application (both semantically and "technically" if you want to call it so). There are many applications without a window, and there are many applications with multiple windows (and, if we get technical here, there are "conceptual applications" with many "programatical `Application` classes running on several `AppDomain`s). In WPF there's the concept of `MainWindow`, which you can find in `Application.Current.MainWindow`, but that's runtime information and I wouldn't use that for binding in a view to itself. `RelativeSource` (or `local`) is the right tool

Comment: @Jcl You're right, of course. Hence my comment that I **assumed** and didn't **reason**. The window is called "application" in this context because it's the "physical" manifestation of the program I'm creating and the only thing that is visible to the user. C.f. when people refer to the screen as "the computer". But, once again - you're right in your remark and I do agree with you.