# WPF Binding to Property of Element of ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

I'm working with a DataGrid in WPF and I'm trying to perform some data binding that it a little more complex than I'm used to.  I have an ObservableCollection of a class that also implements an ObservableCollection of a subclass.  I'm trying to bind the IsChecked property of a CheckBox to a value on that subclass and no matter when I try I can't seem to get it to work.  Hopefully I'm just missing something simple.

In my main program I have the following, and it works fine for detecting changes to "SomeProperty" on the "MyDevice" class:

```
ObservableCollection<MyDevice> MyDevices = new ObservableCollection<MyDevice>();
DevicesGrid.ItemSource = MyDevices;
```

My class definition is below:

```
public class MyDevice : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public class Input : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string PropertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }

        private bool _SyncDetected;
        public bool SyncDetected
        {
            get { return _SyncDetected; }
            set { _SyncDetected = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string PropertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
    }

    private bool _SomeProperty;
    public bool SomeProperty
    {
        get { return _SomeProperty; }
        set { _SomeProperty = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Input> MyInputs = new ObservableCollection<Input>() { new Input(), new Input() };
}
```

And this is my XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DevicesGrid" Margin="10,80,10,10" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridRow}}">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource DeviceRowContextMenu}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Sync/Hotplug" IsReadOnly="True" Width="Auto">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2,2,2,2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <CheckBox Margin="2,2,2,2" IsHitTestVisible="False" IsChecked="{Binding MyInputs[0].SyncDetected}" Content="In1"/>
                        <CheckBox Margin="2,2,2,2" IsHitTestVisible="False" IsChecked="{Binding MyInputs[1].SyncDetected}" Content="In2"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>        
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I'm really new at working with WPF so any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: If there are only two CheckBox, why do you need an observablecollection?

Comment: or alternatively, if you're using an observablecollection you should instead be using an ItemsCollection to display the check boxes

Comment: why don't you bind to MyDevices:     <DataGrid x:Name="DevicesGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding MyDevices}" Margin="10,80,10,10" AutoGenerateColumns="False">

Comment: What exactly is it that isn't working?  I can't see anything immediately wrong (other than its not really the right way to do things) with the above

Comment: @TimRutter It doesn't show the correct data as it never seems to update.  What's the difference between `ItemsSource="{Binding MyDevices}"` and `DevicesGrid.ItemSource = MyDevices;` in C# code?  I'll research ItemsCollection, but in the meantime can you offer more advice about what I'm doing 'not really the right way'?

Comment: read about MVVM. SO isn't really here to advise on the best way to do things.  There are many ways to achieve what you want.  If you are having specific problems then post them and people will assist.  Tt sounds to me like you need to do some more research.  Read a book, use online resources etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something wrong:

```
public ObservableCollection<Input> MyInputs = new ObservableCollection<Input>() { new Input(), new Input() };
```

`MyDevice.MyInputs` is a [*field*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields), not a property, so [the binding system cannot find it through reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11635249/3165499).

Comment: Thanks.  That was it.